# Is the execution time difference (between a function with pass by reference and pass by value) significant in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, pass-by-reference, pass-by-pointer

For Leetcode question 1312 ,I implemented a pass by value solution and my execution time for a testcase was above 120ms, for the same test case in a pass by reference the execution time drastically reduced to about 8ms , HOW? 
Here are both solutions:

120ms + solution /  not accepted:

```
 class Solution {
public:
    vector< vector<int> > dp;
    int insert(string s,int l,int r)
    {

        if(dp[l][r]!=-1)
            return dp[l][r];
        else if(l>=r)
            return 0;

        if(s[l]==s[r])
            dp[l][r] = insert(s,l+1,r-1)  ;
        else 
            dp[l][r] = 1 + min(  insert(s,l+1,r), insert(s,l,r-1) ) ;

        return dp[l][r];
    }

    int minInsertions(string s) {
        dp.resize(s.length()+1, vector<int> (s.length()+1,-1) );
        return insert(s,0,s.length()-1);
    }
};
```

~8ms solution :

```
   class Solution {
public:
    vector< vector<int> > dp;
    int insert(string& s,int l,int r)
    {

        if(dp[l][r]!=-1)
            return dp[l][r];
        else if(l>=r)
            return 0;

        if(s[l]==s[r])
            dp[l][r] = insert(s,l+1,r-1)  ;
        else 
            dp[l][r] = 1 + min(  insert(s,l+1,r), insert(s,l,r-1) ) ;

        return dp[l][r];
    }

    int minInsertions(string& s) {
        dp.resize(s.length()+1, vector<int> (s.length()+1,-1) );
        return insert(s,0,s.length()-1);
    }
};
```

I have a couple of questions:

- Why is the difference so significant?
- Does it happen only for strings, I mean do primitive/built-in data-types behave in the same way?
- Would pass by pointer result in the same execution as pass by reference?
- Also, according to my understanding of a reference variable, it points to the same address except that it has another name, is this correct?

Thank You.

Comment: I all depends on the size of what it is you are passing. If you pass by value, you force a copy be created to be passed to the function. If you pass by reference -- you are essentially passing a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is the execution time difference (between a function with pass by reference and pass by value) significant in C++?

It can be significant, and it can be insignificant. It depends.

> I implemented a pass by value solution and my execution time for a testcase was above 120ms, for the same test case in a pass by reference the execution time drastically reduced to about 8ms

The result of this experiment demonstrates quite clearly a case where the time difference appears to be significant - although without information about variance of the measurements, we cannot be certain that the results are significant statistically.

> Why is the difference so significant?

You can find out using a profiler. Given that the change of the argument to a reference appears to improve the speed significantly, it would be reasonable to guess that most of the time is spent on creating multiple copies of the argument.

> Does it happen only for strings

It doesn't happen only for strings. You'll find that there are other types that are slow to copy as well.

> I mean do primitive/built-in data-types behave in the same way?

Probably not.

How much time does it take to copy an integer? Integers are usually a 1-8 bytes. It takes a about single instruction.

How much time does it take to copy a string? How big even is a string? Even `sizeof(std::string)` is more than the largest integer type on your system. Then there is the dynamic array, which may potentially be gigabytes in size. Copying a gigabyte takes more time than copying 8 bytes. Even if the string isn't that massive, its copy may involve dynamic allocation. Dynamic allocation is much slower than simply copying an integer.

> Would pass by pointer result in the same execution as pass by reference?

You can find out by measuring. But I can tell you that yes.

Comment: also I think since there's recursion, the time difference is significant.